# iOS In App Purchase - "Invalid Product ID" in release, NOT development version

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I created a new app and uploaded the binary to iTunes Connect, then tested IAP using the test user account, both on the simulator and on the device. Both worked.

I submitted the final app and it is currently live on the App Store. However, after deleting the development version from my device and downloading my app from the App Store to test IAP, the app immediately receives an "Invalid Product ID:" error.

Once again, the development version worked using the test user account, but live on the store it does not work and returns invalid product ID. Any ideas what this might be? If anyone wants to test this (in case it's just me) the app is called "ContaX" and is free with ads - you don't need to actually buy the upgrade, just see if it crashes after tapping the remove ads option.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to wait for 24 hours after your app is approved.

Sometimes it takes more time for the in app purchases to be available in the released application.

Comment: I second this. I just submitted a new app that had an in-app purchase and it took almost 48 hours after the app was in the store before the in-app purchase showed up and worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am also suffering with this issue and my app has rejected two time due to this issue. I went to Apple Developer Forum to get the solution. The problem is might be with Review team's device or environment.

Here is the link of full thread: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/233371
I think it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the bundle ID you've submitted the app under and the product IDs you're sending to the app.  They have to match.

You may have accidentally submitted an app with a different bundle ID.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting this problem for a while I realized I was using the "Apple ID" to get the In App Purchases rather than the "Product ID". So, make sure you're using the "Product ID" and NOT the product's "Apple ID"!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share our experience. One of our apps did not have any purchase since release. It was over a month. We have tested in app purchase during development phase in sandbox mode, everything was ok.

When we deleted the development app from our device and installed the app from the app store, we got `Invalid product id` during purchase.

We double checked everything and tried many things. What we think done the trick is toggle "**Cleared for Sale**" in the iTunes connect.

We have 3 auto renewing subscriptions. In IAP page, We uncheck `Cleared for Sale.` then save, then again recheck `Cleared for Sale`, saved again on each product. remove app from the phone and download again from App Store.

Nothing seems to happen. After 30 minutes suddenly one auto renewing subscription started working. 2 other subscriptions still didn't work. After 5 hours all 3 subscriptions started working magically.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing something similar. On a new tvOS app with 8 auto-renew subscription IAPs, for the first 30 hours or so after release, none of the IAPs were available. Then one became available and now we are at 40 hours since release with still only 1 of 8 IAPs available.