# In-App-Purchase invalid product id only on release version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I released a new version of an app yesterday which added in app purchases.  We did testing with a test account in sandboxed mode and everything worked correctly, however once we download the app from the app store the `SKProductsRequestDelegate` method:

```
(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

returns invalid product id's instead of valid ones.  I'm baffled because I've had these types of problems before but only when trying to get them to work in debug mode, never after the app has been released from the app store.  I've double checked everything on the list here http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ and none of those are the problem.

Here's another thread which is exactly my problem but no solution here: [iOS In App Purchase - "Invalid Product ID" in release, NOT development version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371184/2766755)

Comment: Have the products been submitted for review and approved?

Comment: Yes.  This was an update to an app already in the store and the products were submitted with the newest binary.  They have been approved and are marked "cleared for sale" in iTunes connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in app purchases are magic.  At around 8 pm we noticed that things started working normally.  We had previously filed a request for help from Apple but never received a response so I'm not sure if that's what kicked off the fix or if it was just one of those things we needed to wait on.

Answer (score 2):

I also encounter this problem and after 22 hours the problem be fixed automated. So I think this is the app store's problem that apple need some time to add your iap ID in their server.

Comment: Same with me. It's fixed after waiting 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

I am also suffering with this issue and I went to Apple Developer Forum to get the solution. The problem is might be with Review team's device or environment.

Here is the link of full thread: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/233371